# GeoJSOn or WFS service to view, edit and save geometries

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, geojson

To view, edit and save in postgis geometries using OpenLayers + Geoserver 
what is recomenadado use GeoJSON or serivços WFS? 
I ask this for performance and additionally want the edition is recorded in the database realtime.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you read the features as GeoJSON, I think you probably need to use [WFS-T](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/1629) to modify features.

WFS-T allows you to add, delete and update WFS features. GeoServer supports WFS-T.

Boa Sorte!

Comment: I understand, I'm also reading about the rest api geoserver with which I can add, delete and update my features. Among geoserver WFS-T and rest api which has the best performance? What is recommended for a small amount of data will be around a 30 shapes most type point the biggest one containing about 500 feições.Sendo that these data are not changed very often, longer queries that change.